# How to resolve time data does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, formatting

Suppose I have a date value in a pandas dataframe column that looks like this:

```
2015/06/30 00:00:00
```

I want it to look like this to match the format `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'`:

```
06/30/2015 00:00:00
```

I suppose I need to have a function to change all values in that column to the new format but I am not sure how to flip the date so the year is at the end.

```
def fix_date(row):
    date_str = row.PRELIM_DATE
    if date_str is not None:
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

The above crashes. How can I rearrange my dates to the proper format?

Comment: The format of your datetime is not default, this works: pd.to_datetime('2015/06/30 00:00:00', format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') and returns Timestamp('2015-06-30 00:00:00')

Comment: To change the format, you can use strftime but the result would be of type object and NOT datetime, pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')